# document.createElement() Function Runs Only Once

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I am trying to create a button loop using the document.createElement() function in JavaScript. The function will successfully create a button, and the said button can run a function fine. The problem comes in when trying to remove, and re-create the button.

The desired output is as follows: When the 'Create Button' is pressed, it will create a button, called 'Continue'. When 'Continue' is pressed, the page will reset back to the default with 'Create Button' being displayed. You should be able to continue pressing these two buttons indefinitely.

This works, *but only once.*

After the 'Continue' button is pressed, the function `parentNode.removeChild()` function is ran for 'Continue'. This successfully deletes 'Continue', but it also, for some reason or another, prevents it from being created ever again.

Another method I've tried is using `document.getElementById().style.display = "none"`, but, without the presence of `parentNode.removeChild()`, every time the 'Continue' button's function is run, it creates duplicates of itself.

Basically, it either creates itself once and never again, or will create another of itself every time it runs.

Here's a code block using the `parentNode.removeChild()` function

```js
function displayContinue() {

  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";

  var cont = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  cont.innerHTML = "Continue";
  document.getElementById("button2").appendChild(cont);
  var remove = document.getElementById("button2");

  cont.onclick = function cont() {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "inline";
    remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
  }

}
//Function Output: Continue appears only the first time 'Create Button' is pressed
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Button Loop</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Create Button -->
  <button id="button1" onclick="displayContinue()">Create Button</button>

  <!-- Place For Continue to Appear-->
  <p id="button2"></p>

  <!-- Create Button's Function -->
  <script type="text/Javascript">



  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Additionally, here is a sample using the `document.getElementById().style.display = "none";` command

```js
function displayContinue() {

  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "inline";

  var cont = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  cont.innerHTML = "Continue";
  document.getElementById("button2").appendChild(cont);
  var remove = document.getElementById("button2");

  cont.onclick = function cont() {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none";
  }

}
//Function Output: 'Continue' is duplicated every time 'Create Button' is pressed
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Button Loop</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Create Button -->
  <button id="button1" onclick="displayContinue()">Create Button</button>

  <!-- Place For Continue to Appear-->
  <p id="button2"></p>

  <!-- Create Button's Function -->
  <script type="text/Javascript">



  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There has to be something I'm missing here. What is the solution?

Comment: You start with button2. But your first iteration you remove button2. You do not ever add button 2 back in. When it tries to append to button2 on all subsequent iterations, it cannot find it, so it fails there.

Comment: Don't remove the `button2` paragraph, just remove the button that's the child of it.

Comment: @tmdesigned Button2 was added via variable, correct? And appended through a document command. How do I manually add 'button2' back in, without using a variable?

Comment: You're getting confused because you gave your paragraph the id "button2". Instead, give it a more meaningful name, like "button-container". Then, add an remove buttons from the container, not the container itself.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, Barmar,   Thanks guys, that definitely fixed it. Sometimes I get stuck in my head a bit. From what I can tell, though, I can't mark your comments as answer. Care to make one so I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
function displayContinue() {
  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";

  var contBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  contBtn.innerHTML = "Continue";

  document.getElementById("button2").appendChild(contBtn);
  var remove = document.getElementById("button2");

  contBtn.onclick = function cont() {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "inline";
    contBtn.parentNode.removeChild(contBtn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cont()
{
    document.getElementById("button2").remove();
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display="inline";
}
function displayContinue()
{
    var button2=document.createElement("button");
    button2.id="button2";
    button2.innerHTML="Continue";
    button2.onclick=cont;
    document.getElementById("button2holder").appendChild(button2);
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Button Loop</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button1" onclick="displayContinue()">Create Button</button>
        <span id="button2holder"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

What this does is it creates the `Create Button` button, and it's `onclick` function is `displayContinue`.  `displayContinue` creates `button2`, and then sets its `id`, `innerHTML`, and `onclick` function.  Then it `appendChild`s `button2` into `button2holder`, the container of `button2`.  After that, it hides `button1` using `.style.display="none";`

The `onclick` function of the `Continue` button is the `cont` function.  The first thing it does is `remove()` `button2`.  You can just do `el.remove()` to remove an element, instead of `.parentNode.removeChild(el)`.  And then it gives `button1` a `display:inline`, because `button`s are by default `inline`.

I have tested this code and it seems to work.  Put in the comments if it worked for you!

Comment: This was essentially the code I've used for my original HTML page, since finding an answer on this forum. If I can, I'll mark this as an additional answer, since this is also a perfect solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for considering this!  I hope you do really well on whatever you're building! 